# How do I create a table to show the count by each data type in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I am trying to create a table to see how many variables of any data type, I have in the dataset. The columns are many. The code I am using looks like this:

```
type_dct = {str(k): list(v) for k, v in df.groupby(df.dtypes, axis=1)}
```

The issue is that the output is unreadable as I have many columns and the output gives the name of all the columns under each data type. Which is not required. I just want a tabular representation of data types and their count. I have used .info() as well. Again the long list of entries as output is difficult to comprehend. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `pandas.DataFrame` is called `df`

```py
df.dtypes.value_counts()
```

Comment: this doesn't work if you want to distinguish between dictionaries and lists for example, return object

Comment: I am sorry, but I believe the the question assumes that the dataset is a pandas.DataFrame given the tag. Of course it doesn't work for list or dicts.

Comment: but in each cell could contain a dictionary, this question has already been asked this morning